# What is the order of initializing local variables and running statements in a function (+memory order)?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-model

For the following code, will the Lock object be initialized after or before the first statement?

```
int* data = NULL;
int* example() {
  if (data) return data;

  Lock lock;
  data = new int[10];
  return data;
}
```

I know it should work as expected in this way:

```
int* data = NULL;
int* example() {
  if (data) return data;

  {
    Lock lock;
    if (!data)
      data = new int[10];
  }
  return data;
}
```

But do both methods above work in multiple threads on a weak memory order machine? I tried to search but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: avoid `NULL` and use `nullptr` instead(c++11). Avoid returning dynamically  created memory. Use RIII instead. Lastly you have a memory leak, your void function does not return a pointer so you can;t deallocate it after the function execution

Comment: Neither approach works, actually according to the C++ standard: reading `data` has a data-race with initializing `data` resulting in undefined behavior. Just use `int* example() { static int* rc = new int[10]; return rc; }`

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are initialized when execution passes through the point of their definition. That is, your first implementation of `example()` is equivalent to (this even incorrect use of double-checked locking - it omits the second check in addition to having a data-race...):

```
int* example() {
    if (data)
        return data;

    {
        Lock lock; // (this really needs to reference some already initialized mutex
        data = new int[10];
        return data;
    }
}
```

Assuming your `Lock` class acquires a suitably initialized mutex, the code still has a data-race according to the C++ standard: reading `data` in the `if`-statement and the `return`-statement is not synchronized with setting `data` later. As a result, all of these functions result in undefined behavior according to the C++ standard. A simple fix avoiding all of the problems is to rely on the guarantees for initializating function-local `static` variables:

```
int* example() {
    static int* rc = new int[10];
    return rc;
}
```

The initialization of `rc` has to be done in a thread-safe way. If multiple threads try to initialize `rc` concurrently, only one thread will manage to do so while all other threads are blocked until the initializaton is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain more about "reading data in the if-statement and the return-statement is not synchronized with setting data later"?

Comment: @user3701366: The statement `if (data)` reads the value of data. At this point, there is no synchronization (e.g., a lock or data being atomic). Another thread may write `data`, though. The write uses a lock but since the read is unsynchronized there is still a data-race between the read and the write.